# How do I add a new view with angular ui-router

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router, url-routing

I have a project that was reworked for me recently. The new code is much cleaner but I am not sure how to add additional views. I have four categories with an html and an index.js for each category. The index.js file has code like this:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var template = fs.readFileSync(__dirname + '/groups.html', 'utf-8');

module.exports = function(angular) {
  return angular.module('myApp.groups', [])
    .config(['$stateProvider', function($stateProvider) {
        $stateProvider
          .state('groups', {
            url: '/groups',
            template: template,
            controller: 'GroupsCtrl'
          })
           .state('groupsAdd', {
            url: '/groupsAdd',
            views:{
                "groupsAdd":{
                   templateUrl: "groupsAdd.html",
                   controller:"GroupsCtrl"
                 }
              }
        });
     }])
    }])

    .controller('GroupsCtrl', [function() {

    }]);
};
```

I would like to route to a new page called groupsAdd.html from a button located in the groups.html file. I've tried to add the groupAdd view in StateProvider but I am obviously doing something wrong.

The routing in apps.js is very confusing to me:

```
angular.module('myApp', [
  'ui.router',
  require('./views/carriers')(angular).name,
  require('./views/groups')(angular).name,
  require('./views/employees')(angular).name,
  require('./views/products')(angular).name,
  require('./views/user')(angular).name
]).
config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider', function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/login');
}]);
```

But I know the answer is in these two .js files! any help or suggestions would be great. Thanks.

Comment: Did you read the examples from the [ui-router repo](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router) and still have this problem?

Comment: Just change url: to templateUrl: and you're done! This one's pretty tricky though...